# "make eclipse-project" - problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello to all,

i followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs).
At this Step:

> Open a terminal, roscd into the folder
> of your package, and execute:
>
> make eclipse-project
>
> You will now find two Eclipse files in
> your package. It is not recommended to
> add them to the repository, as they
> contain absolute links and will be
> different for different users checking
> out your software.

**no** ecplise files are generated in my package.
Following text is shown by the terminal:

```
faps@UbuntuBioMech:~/ros_workspace/test$ make eclipse-project 
mv Makefile Makefile.ros if ! (cmake -G"Eclipse
CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -Wno-dev . &&
rm Makefile && rm CMakeCache.txt && rm
-rf CMakeFiles); then mv Makefile.ros Makefile && echo "**ERROR building
Eclipse project!**" && false; fi
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Could not determine Eclipse version, assuming at least 3.6
(Helios). Adjust CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION
if this is wrong.
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3") [rosbuild]
Building package test [rosbuild]
Cached build flags older than
manifests; calling rospack to get
flags [rosbuild] Including
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/rospy/rosbuild/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roslisp/rosbuild/roslisp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/faps/ros_workspace/test mv
Makefile.ros Makefile mv .project
.project-cmake awk -f
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/mk/eclipse.awk
.project-cmake     .project rm
.project-cmake python
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/mk/make_pydev_project.py
Creating pydev project for package
'test' Writing .pydevproject, adding
25 modules
```

Any Ideas what is going wrong? Many Thanks in advance,
Dominik

executing  ls .project, the terminal shows:

```
faps@UbuntuBioMech:~/ros_workspace/test$ ls .project 
.project
```

Eclipse cant find any project-files in the directionary.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42201/%22make-eclipse-project%22---problem/) by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the project file is being generated correctly.

Now you only need to import it to your project into Eclipse. For that you should start eclipse from a terminal where the ROS-related environment variables are defined (they should be if you added the line *source /opt/ros/ROS_VERSION/setup.bash* to your .bashrc file).

To make it easier I have this launcher in $HOME/Desktop/eclipse.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=bash -i -c "PATH_TO_ECLIPSE/eclipse"
Icon=PATH_TO_ECLIPSE/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Integrated Development Environment
MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;
Categories=Eclipse;Development; IDE;
InitialPreference=9
```

Once Eclipse is running go to File->Import...

Select "Existing Projects into Workspace" on the dialog and click "Next"

Choose "Select root directory" and click the button "Browse...". Now navigate until you find the folder where your ROS project is stored and select it. (You will not be able to see the .project file on the list, but that is fine, just hit the "OK" button.)

Now the project name will appear on the Projects list. Click the "Finish" button and you are done!

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems nothing is going wrong.

The error message early in the log is never printed out really, you just see it there because it is part of the if/then command.

Are you sure no eclipse files are being generated?

Check:

$ ls .project

EDIT:
As you can see, the .project file was generated, so everything is all right. Please be more precise when you say Eclipse does not find any project files. You need to import the project into your eclipse workspace.

EDIT2:
Project files are hidden files, so your eclipse dialog might not show them. You umight right-click the dialog to show hidden files. However eclipse is also fine with you just giving the folder name. If eclipse gives you an error, please post the error in your question.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6